# Hiding some of the options in ascx page

Tags: asp.net

I have a list of search options in a page which I can hide using some collapse button like click here. Now I wanted to make this option collapse by default. when even the user wants to expand then he can use this button and expand.
How can I make this default?

my code in ascx page is like this.

```
 <span class="hintText">
            <asp:Label ID="lblClickHere" runat="server" Text="(click Here)"       meta:resourcekey="lblClickHereResource1"></asp:Label>
        </span>
```

I have an icon which I am using for expanding and collapsing. code for icon display is:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="showhide" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="../common/images/show-icon.png"
            Height="21" Width="21" OnClientClick="javascript:return controlSearchBar();" />
```

To expand and collapse I have written some java script. By default it will show all the options. My java script is here:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=searchBar.ClientID%>').show();
    $('#<%=showhide.ClientID%>').attr("title", "Hide SearchBar")
    $('#<%=showHideFlag.ClientID%>')[0].value = "showing";
    $('#<%=showhide.ClientID%>').attr("src", "../common/images/hide-icon.png");
});

function controlSearchBar() {
    if ($('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar').is(":hidden")) {
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar').slideDown("fast");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("src", "../common/images/hide-icon.png");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("title", "Hide SearchBar")
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showHideFlag')[0].value = "showing";
    } else {
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar').slideUp("fast");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("src", "../common/images/show-icon.png");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("title", "Show SearchBar")
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showHideFlag')[0].value = "hiding";
    }
```

can anyone help on this?
The expansion and collapse of the button should retain its session through pagenation and tab change.

Comment: Do you have any actual code?  All you have provided is the declaration of the `asp:Label`.  There is not enough information here to get the context of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make serchBar collapse by default to call `controlSearchBar` like as below.

**Jquery Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=searchBar.ClientID%>').show();
    $('#<%=showhide.ClientID%>').attr("title", "Hide SearchBar")
    $('#<%=showHideFlag.ClientID%>')[0].value = "showing";
    $('#<%=showhide.ClientID%>').attr("src", "../common/images/hide-icon.png");

    controlSearchBar();
});
```

But a better solution is below.

**ascx Code:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="showhide" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="../common/images/show-icon.png"
            Height="21" Width="21" OnClientClick="javascript:return switchSearchBar();" />
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    controlSearchBar(true);
});

function switchSearchBar() {
    if ($('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar').is(":hidden")) {
        controlSearchBar(true);
    } else {
        controlSearchBar(false);
    }
}

function controlSearchBar(show) {
    if (show) {
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar').slideDown("fast");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("src", "../common/images/hide-icon.png");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("title", "Hide SearchBar")
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showHideFlag')[0].value = "showing";
    } else {
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar').slideUp("fast");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("src", "../common/images/show-icon.png");
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showhide').attr("title", "Show SearchBar")
        $('#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showHideFlag')[0].value = "hiding";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a jQuery accordion (or bootstrap) ?

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

You can reduce the amount of code you are writing